# Pentaho Kettle PDI - Use ETL Metadata injection with data validator

Tags: validation, etl, code-injection, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

In the official documentation, I read that it is possible to dynamically set the fields in the Data Validator object using ETL Metadata Injection.
Thanks

I've watched some videos on YouTube about the ETL Metadata object, but I haven't found any examples of how to use it with Data Validator. I'm having some difficulty understanding how to implement my transformations. Could someone help me with an example?

My need is to extract data quality rules from a configuration table (field, conversion mask, etc.) and then apply them to the data in a staging table.

Comment: Can you build an example with test data that we can reproduce so we can try to help you? Also, not with the Data Validator, but you have an example on how to implement Metadata Injection in the samples directory of your installation of PDI. Metadata Injection can be tricky to understand (at least for me) so taking a look at the example can help to understand how it works.